# Sort function in Query in Google Sheets

Tags: date, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

In google sheets, I want to sort a query function based on the date in my data. The date is in column V. I replaced my function with
`"Select Q, R, S, T, U, V, W where 1=1 ORDER BY V asc"`

to

`=QUERY(Q2:Y,"SELECT Q, R, S, T, U, V, W WHERE 1=1 "&IF(A3="All Destinations", ""," AND LOWER(R) = LOWER('"&A3&"') ")&IF(B3="All Items", ""," AND LOWER (S) = LOWER('"&B3&"') ")&IF(C3="All Dates", ""," AND V >= DATE '"&TEXT(C3,"YYY-MM-DD")&"' "),1)`

Data is being displayed on the drop-downs based on A3,B3,C3.

I want the data from the query function to organize the data by the date. What can I add to this? Is my syntax incorrect? Apologize in advance if this is an easy solution, I'm new to Google Sheets.

Thank you, kindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=QUERY(Q2:Y, 
 "select Q,R,S,T,U,V,W 
  where 1=1 "&
 IF(A3="All Destinations",," and lower(R) = '"&LOWER(A3)&"'")&
 IF(B3="All Items",," and lower(S) = '"&LOWER(B3)&"'")&
 IF(C3="All Dates",," and V >= date '"&TEXT(C3, "YYYY-MM-DD")&"'
  order by V"), 1)
```

[image]

Comment: I did that and it didn't sort the data... To clarify, I want the data to be sorted by column V in ascending order.

Comment: @johnvs can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: @johnvs answer updated